# Problem with "If"/"else" statement in python

Tags: python

I am just getting started learning, and I've been trying for awhile to get this done but I don't know what I am doing wrong

```
name = input("Enter name :")
if name is "Uber":
    print("Hello there, General "+ name ,",you are a bold one!")
else:
    print("Begone, " + name , ", you do not belong here.")
```

I want it to say "Hello there, General Uber, you are a bold one!" if the input is Uber, otherwise it must say "Begone (name),you do not belong here."

Comment: and what is your code returning instead?

Comment: `is` should be `==`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried using = not ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is` is used for comparing the *identity* of objects, and the input and `"Uber"`  are not the same object.

To test for *equality*, use `==`:

```
if name == "Uber":
```